# How to "filter" out a list in Python , without losing the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, modeling, representation

We have a group of people.  They are randomly assigned a number each week from 0 to 10 and if the number is greater than 9 so they become leaders .If they are more than 1 people, they all become leaders, if they don't , they vote themselves for the leader. A person can't be a leader for more than 2 times in a row.

Anyway, let's only have 10 people and give some random numbers , for this question :

```
import random

people=[]
for i in range(10):
    inputval = random.randint(0,10)
    people.append(inputval)

print(people)
```

So we get :

```
[5, 6 ,7, 4, 8, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

So , these are the values that correspond to the people.

people[0] = 5, people[1] = 6 and so on...

Leader is people[9]

The next week , we have

```
people = [8, 4 ,3, 2, 6, 10, 7, 6, 1, 9 ]
```

So the leaders are people[5]  and people[9]

Next week we have:

```
people = [9, 0 ,4 , 8, 7, 6, 2, 3 , 1, 9 ]
```

So the leaders should be people[0] and people[9] but people[9] is already a leader 2 times in a row, so only people[0] should be leader. You get my drift.
**The problem is how to implement it.**

1. I can name which ones are leaders by enumerating the indices a but that's very "amateurish" way to only print the leaders of each week. I can't keep score of which actually are the leaders each time, with their corresponding indexes.
2. I can also create a new list named leaders. I will run through the people list, if the value the element is 9 and over , it will append the new list with 1 (leader) or 0 (for non-leader), and have something like
   `leaders1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`,  `leaders2=[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]`, printout each time only those with value 1, and compare with the previous leaders list, and probably implement a counter (?).

I find it more complicated in the long run, especially if I want to run this method for many weeks, thus creating more and more lists to compare.

What would be the best solution to that ? Any way to filter out the leaders, without losing the index of people, like [5], [9], etc?  Maybe the solution shouldn't be with lists at all?

Thank you.

Comment: the creativity of describing Homework gets better and better, SO is not a programming service

Comment: If you are stuck in a very specific situation, please paste your code and point out the issue. If not, there are stuff like searching, asking in programming subreddits or forums, that can help you. Although I feel you haven't even started to work on your homework.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This isn't a homework. I'm self-learning languages, and try examples and ideas via Youtube videos. You can put a reminder and answer me a year from now, if you think that this is I'm looking for.
Also, I didn't request for you the answer in code, but rather an idea of what's best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is one of **representation**.
You are presenting it as "how to filter a list", but in fact, the problem is how to determine the successive leaders that are assigned following a strict set of rules.

There may be very clever ways to represent this with lists, or binary numbers, with bit shifting operations... this is the legacy of the pioneers of computer science that had to do things with very limited memory and very limited computer power...

You most likely do not have this problem, therefore you can represent your problem in an intelligible way, and leave code minimalistic antics to nostalgia and code golf.

Maybe modeling the problem with a `class Person` that keeps a historical record of successive scores and appointments as a leader, and is able to self determine if it currently qualifies as a leader?

```
import random


class Person:
    """stores a score, and a history of leadership, that allows it
    to decide if it qualifies a the current leader.
    """
    def __init__(self, ndx):
        self.ndx = ndx
        self.score_history = []
        self.leadership_history = []
    def add_new_score(self, score):
        self.score_history.append(score)
        self.current_leader()
    def current_leader(self):
        if self.score_history[-1] >= 9:
            current_leader = True
        else:
            current_leader = False
        if current_leader and len(self.score_history) >= 3:
            if self.leadership_history[-2] and self.leadership_history[-1]:
                current_leader = False
        self.leadership_history.append(current_leader)
    def is_current_leader(self):
        return self.leadership_history[-1]
    
def assign_score(people):
    for p in people:
        p.add_new_score(random.randint(0, 10))
        print(p.score_history[-1], end=' ')
    print()
        
def get_leaders(people):
    for p in people:
        if p.is_current_leader():
            print(p.ndx, end=' ')
    print()
    
people = [Person(idx) for idx in range(10)]
print()
for _ in range(20):
    print(_, end='\n')
    assign_score(people)
    get_leaders(people)
#     input()
    print()
```

Comment: This is why I think I'm not made for code (and why I gave up Java). While your answer it is more advanced than my progress, I really understand the method. And this how I want to learn to think about things! Very insightful! Thank you! 

Thank you !

Comment: You are very welcomed. Sometimes, during some phases of a learning process, you need to be given permission to do certain things... The problem can be solved with lists, indices, and filtering... but there are other ways that you must explore. The `class Person` still uses an index as a unique id for each `Person`; clearly this comes from the original formulation of the problem; you can modify the class, and work on the abstraction (and I encourage you to do that); for instance, a `Person` can have a name and an id number unrelated to its position in a list...

Comment: Yes, it can be solved. I could have done it, and actually did, especially with new lists , as per my 2nd solution. This would be an answer. Some commenters accussed me of homework , but if it were one, I could have provide right away the solution 2, and get done with it . But as an 37 y.o Automation Engineer that tries to self-teach myself , I want to think out of the basic. I want to learn to think more openly, so I can implement this way of thinking in my jobs. I don't want to only work with PLCs and Scada, even though I'm not sure I'm capable of programming. Thanks!!!